# Chrome getComputedStyle() returns wrong RGBA color?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, rgba

1. I set an rgba() bg-color in Chrome (Win7, 19.0.1084.56)
2. I get the background-color with window.getComputedStyle(), & **it is different**
3. I set the retrieved value on a new element
4. I retrieve it again, **its different again**

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zupa/KsuMp/

In my case, the first 4 blocks have the following contents in Chrome:

- bg-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.503906)
- bg-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)
- bg-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.496094)
- bg-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.496094)

In Firefox, I get constant rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.506)

So, this seems to be a bug. Can you prove me wrong or suggest a workaround? I need the color for a wysiwyg editor and this is killing my unit tests.

Comment: Interesting. I guess it is a rounding error. If you use `0.5` as a value – http://jsfiddle.net/Synmu/1/ – you get consistent results (but not `0.5`).

Comment: @toscho - the consistent result it returns is exactly 1/256 away from 0.5, so as I see it converts 0.5 to x7F instead of x80. Which makes sense as they can not map 1.0 to x100 as the highest possible value is xFF. So that may be a tweak to fit the available scale?

Comment: Here is an even worse case: http://jsfiddle.net/zupa/KsuMp/27/ -> goes down rom 10% to 0% OMG. But it is not going down from 11%: http://jsfiddle.net/zupa/KsuMp/29/

Comment: https://crbug.com/453414 - There's already a fix, but they think it's not urgent enough to release it. Please star the issue to get it the attention it needs.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/13754483/357774.

Comment: It's now consistent but still wrong most of the time. For example, Chrome fails with `0.5`, though Firefox fails with `0.555` and IE9 fails with `0.5555555`.

Answer (score 0):

As a work-around, you could try to store the original RGBA color in a data-* attribute (`data-original-background` perhaps?) on your element and use `$().attr()` to get the old color value from there. That way, even though Chrome will round in a weird way, it will at least consistently round each one the same way because they all use the same base value.

Edit: Here is one of your fiddles I modified with the concept
http://jsfiddle.net/aJfPn/1/

Comment: also: even though data-* is called HTML5, since it just adds a new element, it is compatible (via various methods) all the way back to IE6. jQuery implements the correct method to modify the data-* attribute on a per-browser basis so you don't have to worry about it :)

Comment: This is not really an option as I want to update the color states as the selection changes on the page. The problem is, what if the bg-color is not even defined on any given element, rather inherited from a parent element having a class with the color definition? For a local definition, could as well check the style attribute. Thank you though.

Answer (score -1):

In university I learned that you should never ever test if floats are equal because of rounding errors. Just include a tolerance in your test.

Comment: If you assign a float 10.0 and get 9.0 back, and you tell me it is a rounding error, I am fine with it if 9.0 is a stable value. But if I assign it 9.0 and get 8.0 back, than it is not even stable. That was my problem, I did't know to round that fictive 9.0 up or down. By now it seems to be fixed in Chrome.