# How to get the exact RGBa value set through CSS via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

In most browsers I've tried, `rgba()` values seem to be changed once the browser parsed the CSS.

For example, the following CSS:

```
background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

Gives the following CSS value when accessed via `jQuery.css('background-color')` or native `CSSStyleDeclaration.getPropertyValue('background-color')`:

```
rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.498039)
```

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hgFEj/3) with more examples.

Chrome and Safari give different results. Firefox seems to be the only browser that reports the exact value as entered. Is this a bug or by design?

Comment: I'm guessing wildly it has something to do with floating points and how computers process numbers in general.

Comment: Sounds as an illustration of the arbitrary world of developing web applications... :)

Comment: The values seem to be different enough (e.g. 0.01 -> 0.00784314) that floating point precision doesn't seem like the main culprit. I'm wondering if there's any color profile based adjustment going on.

Comment: the "a" in "rgba" is just an 8-bit value. 127/255 is the closest to 0.5 it can come, and it equals 0.498039

Comment: Ah, thanks @MarkHubbart, that makes sense! Safari returns 0.496094 (127/256). One of them must be a bug.

Comment: https://crbug.com/453414 - There's already a fix for Chrome (Blink), but they think it's not urgent enough to release it. Please star the issue to get it the attention it needs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mark Hubbart's comment is correct.

32-bit color breaks down into four 8-bit components, each within the range 0-255: *red*, *green*, *blue*, and *alpha*. We express the *alpha*, or transparency, as a fraction or percentage since it helps us decimal-brained folks get a quicker idea of just how transparent it is. It is actually better thought of as opaqueness (well, *opacity*) since 100% transparent is 0, not 1.

Now, given 255 is the denominator for the *alpha* value, there is no way to express 0.5 exactly. The value you're seeing, 0.498039, comes from the nearest fraction, 127/255 (rounded to 6 decimal places). Safari returns 0.496094 which is 127/256 rounded to 6 decimal places, and to me seems a bug since that implies 257 values. I also doubt Firefox can accurately report 0.5 unless it is rounding to only 2 decimal places.

You can work around this issue in different browsers by creating a jQuery plugin that, on first execution, checks to see what value is returned with a 50% alpha, and adjust all calculations accordingly.

```
parseFloat(
   $('#divWith50PercentAlphaBackgroundStyle')
      .css('background-color')
      .split(',')[3],
   10
)
```

Then, with this value in hand, do a `switch` on it against the values different browsers return, and properly convert to the closest correct value you're expecting.

Comment: https://crbug.com/453414 - There's already a fix for Chrome (Blink), but they think it's not urgent enough to release it. Please star the issue to get it the attention it needs.