# IF condition with background-color in RGBA

Tags: javascript, css, rgba

How to write an **IF** condition in purely **JavaScript** to check if background color of `<li>` tag is equal to particular RGBA color combination.

For example:

```
if(document.getElementById('element').style.backgroundColor == "rgba(213,212,212,0.5)")
{
     alert("MATCHED");
}
else
{
     alert("FAILED");
}
```

But this comparison for IF statement does **NOT** work! Please help!

Comment: Use classes and check them instead of the comparing the colors, your current method is so fragile.

Comment: Like undefined has stated, this is a little bit more complex than just compare a style property to a string. Have you set the inline style for the element? If you haven't, you have to use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle). `style` represents only set inline styles. Also the returned value depends on the used browser. Different values can be received, like `#xxxxxx`, `rgb(xxx, xxx, xxx)` or `rgba(xxx, xxx, xxx, x.x[x])`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CSS value is returned in a particular way.

Try comparing it to: `"rgba(213, 212, 212, 0.5)"`

(spaces after each comma).

Since JavaScript's rounding errors are the worst, and you really don't care about the alpha, you can just cut out the part you need:

```
var color = document.getElementById('element').style.backgroundColor;
color = color.substring(
                          color.indexOf('(') + 1,
                          color.lastIndexOf(color[3] == 'a' ? ',' : ')')
                        );

if (color == '213, 212, 212')
{
    alert("MATCHED");
}
else
{
    alert("FAILED");
}
```

Works whether or not it's `rgb` or `rgba`

If the `background-color` is not defined as an inline-style, you might want to use:

> var color = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('element')).backgroundColor;

instead (of the first line in code).

Comment: I tried printing the returning value in console and I got the following: `rgba(213, 212, 212, 0.498039)`. Why is the alpha value coming this way when the background color of the element has been set to `0.5`?

Comment: JavaScript is really bad when it comes to floating point numbers. Do you really need to compare the alpha part or is it just the rgb?

Comment: I don't mind comparing just the RGB. But the returning value is RGBA. Can this be achieved?

Comment: @rishiJasapara But only as long as you've set an inline style for the element. I'd combine this answer and The Wobbuffet's answer to get a correct value from a stylesheet as well as from an inline style. Anyway, +1 @ ThatWeirdo, though your extracting algorithm is a bit weird ; ).

Comment: Yes! I have set an inline style for those elements because they are dynamically created at run-time.

Comment: Updated to support non-inline styles

Comment: @ThatWeirdo it's not JavaScript's fault, it's actually a bug in Chrome/Blink and Safari/WebKit: https://crbug.com/453414. Please star it so it gets more attention; they already have a fix, but they haven't yet released it! (See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13754483/357774.)

Answer (score 0):

Check

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('element')).backgroundColor
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById('element').style.backgroundColor
```

so your new code would be:

```
if(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('element')).backgroundColor === "rgba(213,212,212,0.5)")
{
     alert("MATCHED");
}
else
{
     alert("FAILED");
}
```

(As you can see, I'm checking with three equal signs because no conversion is necessary.)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ztTx8/)

Comment: Yeah this works fine. But I have the element set with alpha opacity too. I tried printing the returning value in console and I got the following: `rgba(213, 212, 212, 0.498039)`. Why is the alpha value coming this way when the background color of the element has been set to `0.5`?

Comment: @rishiJasapara It's a bug in Chrome/Blink and Safari/WebKit: https://crbug.com/453414. Please star it so it gets more attention; they already have a fix for Chrome/Blink, but they haven't released it! (See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13754483/357774.)